# Setting date and datetime columns dependent from language in EasyAdminBundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony2-easyadmin, easyadmin

I'm using EasyAdminBundle in different languages (english and german). But I've got now the problem that I want to format the date and datetime columns.

For example, I want to have the format 'd/m/Y H:i:s' in English and in German language 'd.m.Y H:i:s'. But I didn't find a solution neither in the symfony (EasyAdminBundle) documentation nor with internet search.

Can you help me?

Note: I found the possibility to set the date format with the "format" parameter (example: - { property: 'password', label: 'Password', format: 'd/m/Y H:i:s' }), but in my case the format should be set dependent from language set by user.

Comment: use js to do this in your template https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better solution to solve this in symfony 4 with EasyAdminBundle.

I'm overriding in `templates\bundles\EasyAdminBundle\default\field_datetime.html.twig` with following code:

```
{%- if(app.request.getLocale() == 'de') -%}
    {%- set valueTitle = value|date('d.m.Y H:i:s') -%}
    {%- set valueText = value|date('d.m.Y H:i:s')|replace({' ': '&nbsp;'}) -%}
{%- else -%}
    {%- set valueTitle = value|date('m/d/Y H:i:s') -%}
    {%- set valueText = value|date('m/d/Y H:i:s')|replace({' ': '&nbsp;'}) -%}
{%- endif -%}
<time datetime="{{ value|date('c') }}" title="{{ valueTitle }}">{{ valueText|raw }}</time>
```

And if the locale is changed another date format is made.